# material-ui alignment problem with buttons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I create a `<IconButton>` it shows under the level of the other elements as you can see in the image where the last icon on the right side is below the other icons.

[image]

```
<IconButton>
  <MoreVertIcon aria-label="show more" />
</IconButton>
```

on [codeSand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-http-58k5k?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Check out my answer, it should help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Material UI why do you use `<span>` instead of using Material UI `<Grid>` ?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-cdn-x52xn?file=/src/App.tsx) is an example with [Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) that automatically aligns them by adding `alignItems="center"` as a property